# Unable to skip specific columns while clearing contents

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to create a script in vba to kick out unwanted contents like `@` which doesn't fall under specific columns, as in 5,8,11 and so on until 20. However, If the content what I wish to get rid of are within those columns, let them as they are.

I've tried so far (can't find any idea to skip the aforesaid columns):

```
Sub SkipColumns()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range, I&

    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For I = 3 To 20
        For Each cel In Ws.Range("A2:A" & Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
            If InStr(cel(1, I), "@") > 0 Then
                cel(1, I).ClearContents
            End If
        Next cel
    Next I
End Sub
```

Check out the image below where shadowed columns should be as they are even if they have `@` signs.
[image]

***What possible condition should I define within the script to achieve that?***

Comment: You want to loop through all the cells in a range, and if you find @ delete the cell contents unless it is in columns 5, 8, 11, 14, 17 or 20?

Comment: Yes, exactly that is @Warcupine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hardcode which columns are skipped you can use Case Select

```
Sub SkipColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range, i As Long, LastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For i = 3 To 20
        Select Case i
            Case 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20
            Case Else
                For Each Cell In ws.Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(LastRow, i))
                    If InStr(Cell, "@") > 0 Then Cell.ClearContents
                Next Cell
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the interval is regular, you can test it within your loop

eg:

```
if Not (I - 2) Mod 3 = 0 Then
   'your find, delete code
End if
```

But you might find the `Replace` method faster:

```
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  Dim R As Range
  Dim LR As Long
  Dim i As Long


Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change to suit
With WS
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    'your code looks for last row in Column A, but you could use a different method, or even whole column

'Create a range of all the rows to process
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(LR, 4))
    For i = 6 To 20 Step 3
        Set R = Union(R, .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(LR, i + 1)))
    Next i
End With

R.Replace What:="@", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows
```

Answer (score 1):

The `For..Next` command set allows for skipping in regular intervals with `Step`. Try this:

```
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

For I = 3 To 20 Step 3
    With Ws
        For Each cel In .Range(.Cells(2, I), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, I).End(xlUp).Row, I+1))
            If InStr(cel.Value, "@") > 0 Then
                cel.ClearContents
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
Next I
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `.Range(.Cells(2, I), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, I).End(xlUp).Row, I+1))` to process both columns?

Comment: haha! Yes. As it's written, it's only performing the test on every 3rd column, as opposed to skipping every 3rd column. I'll amend my answer. Thanks Ron.

Answer (score 1):

you may go like this:

```
Sub SkipColumns()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("E1,H1,K1,N1,Q1,T1,W1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'hide columns you don't want to skip
        .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Replace what:="@", replacement:="", lookat:=xlWhole ' replace in visible cells only
        .Range("E1,H1,K1,N1,Q1,T1,W1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' get hidden columns back visible
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not fully understand your question, maybe you make wrong loop level.

```
For Each cel In Ws.Range("A2:A" & Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
   j=cel.row
   del_YESNO=False
   For I = 3 To 20
      If InStr(cel(j, I), "@") > 0 Then
          del_YESNO=True
          exit for
      End If
   Next I
   if del_YESNO=True then cel(j, I).ClearContents
Next cel
```